# Вызов функции принадлежащей классу Editor, из другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, static

Я нашёл [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422991/call-a-function-in-a-customeditor-script-from-another-script) ответ на мой вопрос, но он не помог. У меня не видит класс WaypointEditor в другом классе. Я подключил нужный `namespace SWS` и написал:

```
...
using SWS;
...
    WaypointEditor editors = (WaypointEditor[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(WaypointEditor));
    if (editors.Length >0)
    {
      editors[0].AddMiniLocalPath(modelListPatn,"111");
    }
...
```

Но у меня по прежнему ругается на класс WaypointEditor,я даже пробовал написать так SWS.WaypointEditor и всё равно ругается компилятор, что нет такого класса.
Сам класс WaypointEditor.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SWS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Waypoint and path creation editor.
    /// <summary>
    [CustomEditor(typeof(WaypointManager))]
    public class WaypointEditor : Editor
    {
        //manager reference
        private WaypointManager script;
     ...
    }
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
      ....
    }
    ...
    public void AddMiniLocalPath(List <Vector3> list,string namePath) {

            path = new GameObject(namePath+"cloneMiniPath");
            path.transform.position = script.gameObject.transform.position;
            path.transform.parent = script.gameObject.transform;
            StartPath();
            placing = true;

            for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++) {
                PlaceWaypoint(list [i]);
            }

            if (wpList.Count < 2)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Not enough waypoints placed. Cancelling.");
                if (path) DestroyImmediate(path);
            }

            placing = false;
            wpList.Clear();
            pathName = "";
            Selection.activeGameObject = path;
        }
        ...
}
```

Класс "UISegmentedControlButtonEditor", в котором надо вызывать функцию AddMiniLocalPath(List  list,string namePath), которая принадлежит классу WaypointEditor:

```
        SavingGroupOFObjects.cs:
        using UnityEngine.UI;
        using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
        using System.Collections;
        using UnityEngine;
        using UnityEditor;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.IO;
        using SWS;

        [ExecuteInEditMode]
        public class SavingGroupOFObjects  : MonoBehaviour {

            public string groupName;

            public GameObject GamObjList;

            public GameObject GObjCPoint;

            public Vector3 CollectionPoint;

            public SWS.PathManager pathCont;

            public int index;

            public virtual void UpdateNodeGUI(Event e, Rect viewRect, GUISkin viewSkin)
            {
                if (GamObjList != null)
                {
                    EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
                    //UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.MarkAllScenesDirty();
                    Debug.Log("Editor Set Dirty");
                }
            }

        }

        [CustomEditor(typeof(SavingGroupOFObjects))]
        public class UISegmentedControlButtonEditor : Editor {
            //private SavingGroupOFObjects saveScripGroup;

            private SerializedObject m_Object;
            private SerializedProperty GamObjList;
            private SerializedProperty groupName;
            private SerializedProperty GObjCPoint;
            private SerializedProperty CollectionPoint;
            private SerializedProperty index;
            //private SerializedProperty SM;
            private SerializedProperty pathCont;

            public override void OnInspectorGUI() {

                m_Object.Update();
                ...
                if(tempGamObjList!=null && tempGObjCPoint!=null) {
                    RTCTankController[]TankC = tempGamObjList.GetComponentsInChildren<RTCTankController> ();
                    for (int i=0;i<TankC.Length;i++) {
                        List <Vector3> modelListPatn = splitLine (TankC [i].transform.position,tempGObjCPoint.transform.position);
                        //SWS.WaypointEditor.AddMiniLocalPath(modelListPatn,"22");
                        GameObject.Find("AllPathManager").GetComponent<SWS.PathManager>();


// тут ошибка /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        WaypointEditor editors = (WaypointEditor[])Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(WaypointEditor));
                        if (editors.Length >0)
                        {
                            editors[0].AddMiniLocalPath(modelListPatn,"111");
                        }
// тут ошибка /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    }
                }
                m_Object.ApplyModifiedProperties();
           }
        ...
    }
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Если не работает в "собранном" виде, а в редакторе работает - все объясняется пространством имен `UnityEditor`. Оно доступно исключительно в редакторе.

Comment: @Александр Даниловский UISegmentedControlButtonEditor наследуется от Editor . Но всё равно не видит в классе UISegmentedControlButtonEditor , класс WaypointEditor. Ваш ответ не объясняет что делать. Можно пример ?

Comment: @Александр Даниловский Не работает и в собранном виде и в редакторе не работает.

Comment: Только сейчас обратил внимание. Метод `AddMiniLocalPath` у вас приватный. Добавьте модификатор `public` и попробуйте снова.

Comment: @Александр Даниловский AddMiniLocalPath public , опечатка в вопросе .... дело в классе WaypointEditor , его не видно вообще , там где я к нему обращаюсь , его красным выделяет редактор.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло перемещение WaypointEditor.cs из Assembly-CSharp-Editor в Assembly-CSharp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Класс судя по названию предназначен для работы только в редакторе. То что вы сделали просто нарушение общей логики работы с редактором. Скорей это ваш класс раз он делает настройку в рамках редактирования точек должен быть перенесен в редактор.

Comment: @KingPeas Да это плохое решение согласен. Пришлось перенести код, в котором надо вызвать функцию в редактор.